# Add class and method name in logs during compile time

Tags: java, logback, lombok

I'm currently using `logback/slf4j` for a JEE application.

I want to add class name and method in logs like :

```
Class1::method1::Log message
```

I know there is a way to add this automatically with Logback Layouts. But I can't use it because of speed issues :

> Generating the method name is not particularly fast. Thus, its use
>   should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Is there another way to do it without speed issues ? (e.g using an Eclipse Plugin to add it at compile time)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to do it automatically at compile time (take into account that some come be be not in a method like initialization blocks.)

One possibility to to create different logger for each method by concatenating the method to the class name at logger creation.